# How to send message through net to mobile?

Tags: php, javascript

currently we are developing website which send sms alert to user for perticular service 
but i am not able to set script which will do the same

Please somebody tell me what will be solution....
Please tell any script or site for this problem

thanks...

Comment: Would probably be best to use an external API. But I'm also interested in some peoples answers.

Comment: See [SMS Gateway service provider with PHP API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528919/sms-gateway-service-provider-with-php-api).

Answer (score 1):

Look for an **[SMS gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway)** to use.

For example, I've used [MessageNet](http://www.messagenet.com.au/) here in Australia.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how you are using messagenet.au services  in php i am having username and password for that

Answer (score 0):

Check [FromSMS solution](http://www.fromsms.net/index_en.htm) - free